# VBA Excel - If condition with LEN function not working as expected

Tags: excel, vba

I have a tricky situation with my one record, which appears in one line in some documents like you can see below:

[image]

Therefore I can't extract my data properly, as the other values are thrown.

[image]

The full macro you can find here:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/m1tYvi

but what I tried to do. I tried to set up the IF condition for the total length of the string, which appears in the concerned cell.

https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-len-function.html

that's why I tried something like this:

```
Dim L As Integer
L = Len("Is there room in the chamber to install a new closure :")#

  Set rngFound = rngSearch.Find(What:=qu(q), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlValues)
        With datTarget
            lrowG = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            If rngFound Is Nothing Then
                    .Cells(lrowG, "G") = "Not found" ' blank
                Else
                        If rngFound > L Then
                          rngFound.Copy
                          .Cells(1, "G").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                           
                          rngFound.Offset(1).Copy
                          .Cells(lrowG, "G").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                        Else
                        rngFound.Copy
                          .Cells(lrowG, "G").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                        End If
                End If
                .Cells(lrowG, ColSort) = datSource.Parent.Name
          End With
```

but unfortunately, it seems not to work. The effect is exactly the same.

Is there any solution to this issue? How can I extract the record I exactly need (case 2) instead of a whole string after the colon or even different data as the offset has been applied?

Comment: `If rngFound > L Then` - should you be calling `Len` on `rngFound` here?

Comment: do you mean rngFound.Len ?

Comment: `Len(rngFound.Value)`?

Comment: Yes, thank you! I will know now how to use the Len function properly!

Comment: Your input form doesn't really encourage consistent data entry - can't that be improved?